# Acoustic transmission condition - different speed of sound

Tags: waves, acoustics, speed

Given two domains with different speed of sound, what are the acoustic transmission conditions?

I know, that there is continuity of velocity and acceleration in the normal direction
$$\frac{\partial\mathbf{u}}{\partial t}\cdot\mathbf{n} = -\nabla \psi \cdot \mathbf{n}$$
with $\mathbf{u}$ being the mechanical displacement and $\nabla \psi = \mathbf{v}$ being the acoustic scalar potential.

Furthermore, there is the continuity of forces
$$\mathbf{\sigma}\cdot \mathbf{n}=-p~\mathbf{n}$$
with $\sigma$ as the mechanical stress tensor and $p$ as the acoustic pressure.

But are there any other transmission conditions I have missed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The full solution of acoustic plane wave transmission across a boundary between dissimilar materials usually proceeds by solving for the impedances of the two media and then expressing the reflection and transmission coefficients in terms of the impedance mismatch at the interface. When done by hand, this becomes a lengthy exercise in complex algebra...

Comment: Are you talking about an interface between two "acoustic" fluids?